# How can we detect SUB character in a file?

Tags: c, string

I recently found out that reading SUB character([ASCII code 26](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/substitute-ascii-code-26.html)) using `fgetc(),fscanf()`(Common functions in C to scan characters) makes both of the interpret it as an error and return EOF. I was wondering if there is any way  to detect SUB character so that I can distinguish between the 'real' end of file and the apparent one.

**Note:** The conclusion I am presently on is that end of file is detected using an error in scanning, as SUB character is used to represent error the task looks impossible. But as notepad seems to read it correctly, I am anticipating some technique using C language that I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: 1) be sure to save the result of `fgetc()` as an `int`. 2) SUB aka  Ctrl^Z, is used by _some_ text files to indicate the last `char` in the file.  Many text files do not use that but instead simply have no more data to be read.  3) Real end-of-file is the End-of-file condition set when `fgetc()` or `fscanf()` returns the `int`, not `char`, EOF.

Comment: @chux (point 3)fgetc() and fscanf() are prototyped to return int. So how are they returning char?. As far as I know, both an error and real end of file makes both the functions return -1.

Comment: Agree both functions return `int`.  It is important that the result is _saved_ in an `int`.  You can find _many_ SO weak coding examples doing something like `char ch = fgetc(stdin); if (ch == EOF) ...`.  Both functions return `EOF` on error/real end of file, not necessarily `-1`.  The C spec does _not_ define `EOF` to be `-1`, but does define it to be negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file(s) in binary mode.

```
...fopen("filename", "rb")...
```

<sup>Don't forget that the library code no longer translates "newlines" in binary mode. If the file has `"\r\n"` pairs to end lines, you'll get both `'\r'` and `'\n'` when reading the file.</sup>